# `UICollectionViewLayout` has no member `itemSize`

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I am a beginner in iOS/Swift development.  When I use the layout's `itemSize` property, I get the following error message, and I don't understand why:

```
Value of type `UICollectionViewLayout` has no member `itemSize`
```

Here is my code:

```
let layout = collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewLayout
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWeight, height: cellHeight)
```

Comment: Please improve your formatting while asking any question so that everyone can understand very easily.

Comment: `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Answer (score 3):

`UICollectionViewLayout` is an abstract base class. You probably want to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, which has the `itemSize` property you're after.

Comment: thanks , i made a mistake in my code .Thanks for your support